# Question in Page 48 of Elementary Number theory by David Burton

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am self studying Elementary number theory by David Burton's book and I could not think about how to prove this inequality .

I am adding its image  highlighting the inequality I am not able to prove.
- [image].

> Proof of Bonse Inequality is easy by using  2nd Principle of induction and Assuming Bertrand Postulate.
>
> But I am unable to prove the highlighted inequality assuming Bertrand postulate and usind 2nd principle of induction.

Can someone please tell how to prove it.

Comment: Slightly different approach:
$$
p_2p_3\cdots p_np_{n+1}-2 \geq (p_{2n}+2)p_{n+1}-2 > p_{2n}p_{n+1} > 4p_{2n} > p_{2n+2}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formulation of [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) which is most useful here is that, for $n \ge 1$,

$$p_{n+1} \lt 2p_n \implies 2p_{n+1} \lt 4p_n \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Increasing $n$ by $1$ and using \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$p_{n+2} \lt 2p_{n+1} \lt 4p_n = 2^2p_n \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

You can use induction (which I'll leave to you) to show that, for any $k \ge 1$, you have

$$p_{n+k} \lt 2^k p_{n} \implies p_{2n} \lt 2^n p_n \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

You have $p_2 p_3 p_4 = 3(5)(7) = 105 \gt 2^6 = 64$. As all other primes with higher indices are greater than $2$, you have for $n \ge 5$ that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
p_2p_3 \cdots p_{n-1}p_n - 2 & \gt 2^6(p_5p_6 \cdots p_{n-1})p_n - 2 \\
& \gt 2^6\left(2^{n-5}\right)p_n - 2 \\
& = 2^{n+1}p_n - 2 \\
& \gt 2^{n}p_n \\
& \gt p_{2n}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

As this is for $n \ge 5$, you now just have to check the specific cases of $n = 3$, which gives $p_6 = 13$ and $p_2 p_3 - 2 = 3(5) - 2 = 13$, and $n = 4$, which gives $p_8 = 23$ and $p_2 p_3 p_4 - 2 = 3(5)(7) - 2 = 103$. Thus, this confirms

$$p_{2n} \le p_2 p_3 \cdots p_n - 2, \; n \ge 3 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

is always true, with the equality only occurring for the $n = 3$ case.