# Question in Condition of solvabillity of Linear Diophantine equation from David Burton

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am studying Elementary number theory from David Burton Elementary number theory and I am unable to think about this argument which author gives in Ch-2.

My doubt is in condition of solvabillity specifically the part when if solution of ax+by= c exists then proving gcd (a, b)  divides c.

I  am adding the image of proof.

[image]

> My doubt is how c = $ d( r x_0 + s y_0) $ implies d |  c as it's a possibility that $ d( r x_0 + s y_0) $  |  c. But why doesn't author considers that possibility?

Can someone please explain!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a \mid b$ means there's an integer $k$ such that $b = ka$. If you have

$$c = d(rx_0 + sy_0) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

then $d$ divides the right side, so you must have that $d$ divides the left side, i.e., $d \mid c$, with the $k$ being $rx_0 + sy_0$ here. Of course, since the $2$ sides of \eqref{eq1A} are equal, you also have $d(rx_0 + sy_0) \mid c$, with $k = 1$ in this case instead.

Since the value of $rx_0 + xy_0$ is basically unknown, and the author is only trying to show that you always have $d \mid c$ in this part of the proof, this is all that is used in the text.

Comment: thanks a lot. Can you please look at this question asked by me if you have some spare time https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3515497/question-in-page-48-of-elementary-number-theory-by-david-burton

Comment: @InvisibleMan You're welcome. As you requested, I've also looked at and provided an answer to your other question.